# When an atomic operation is executed together with a non-atomic operation, is it safe?

Tags: concurrency, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm a computer science student and recently I've been learning about concurrency problems and I'm trying to understand the underlying implementation.
We know that CPU provides some atomic operations like xchg and lock, where lock involves a bus lock.
But while studying, I had a question, if an i++ of an atomic operation is executed along with an i++ of a non-atomic operation, will it be unsafe? Here is the example I came up with:

## Let's assume

`First i=0.
CPU1 executes a non-atomic i++ operation which contains:

1. reading i from memory into a register
2. +1
3. writing i=1 from the register back to the cache line`

## The execution of the program now begins:

(We'll ignore MESI here for now, because even with MESI, it's just more CPU0 sending invalid i and CPU1 re-reading the new cache line.)

1. CPU1 reads the cached i into the register.
2. CPU0 locks the bus, prohibiting CPU1 from reading memory.
3. CPU1 executes i++ and writes i back to memory, finds that it can't write back, waits
4. CPU0 executes i++.
5. CPU0 releases the bus lock.
6. CPU1 retries to write back.
   Eventually i=1.

Comment: On the same memory location?  Safe in what sense?  It won't damage the CPU hardware, but of course the results aren't necessarily the same as two atomic increments.  Being non-atomic, the load part and store part aren't glued together, so the atomic RMW can happen between them and have its value stepped on.   I think the problem is that you're not considering the possibility of the atomic RMW happening between the load and the store of `x.store(x.load()+1)`.  Seems like a duplicate of [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850)

Comment: And of course for types wide enough that a normal load isn't naturally lock-free, you could get tearing in the load or store.  (e.g. uint64_t on 32-bit x86, where you need to use `movq xmm0, [mem]` and then `movd` and `pextrd` or equivalent if you want the data in GP integer regs.  Or just `paddq xmm0, xmm1` / `movq [mem], xmm0` to do a 64-bit add with atomic loads/stores on x86 in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I know the result of two non-atomic operations, and I know the result of two atomic operations, I'm just not quite sure of the result when an atomic operation and a non-atomic operation are executed under a multi-core CPU.
Thanks for the answer, it really helped me out.